# Scala flatmap Seq

Tags: scala

I have an array: Option[Seq[People]]

```
case class People (
   name: Option[String],
   tall: Option[Boolean],
   fat: Boolean
)
```

What I want looks like:

```
String name = "Jack|Tom|Sam"
String tall = "True|True|True"
String fat = "True|False|True"
```

So, I tried:

```
name = array.flatMap(x => x.name).map(_.mkString("|"))
name = array.flatMap(_.slot_name).map(_.mkString("|"))
```

The above tries didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need (demonstrated in a *Scala REPL* session):

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class People (
     |    name: Option[String],
     |    tall: Option[Boolean],
     |    fat: Boolean
     | )
defined class People

scala> val array = Option(
     |   Seq(
     |     People(Some("Jack"), Some(true), true),
     |     People(Some("Tom"), Some(true), false),
     |     People(Some("Sam"), Some(true), true),
     |   )
     | )
array: Option[Seq[People]] = Some(List(People(Some(Jack),Some(true),true), People(Some(Tom),Some(true),false), People(Some(Sam),Some(true),true)))

scala> val name = array.fold("")(_.flatMap(_.name).mkString("|"))
name: String = Jack|Tom|Sam

scala> val tall = array.fold("")(_.flatMap(_.tall).map(_.toString.capitalize).mkString("|"))
tall: String = True|True|True

scala> val fat = array.fold("")(_.map(_.fat.toString.capitalize).mkString("|"))
fat: String = True|False|True
```

Each `fold` operation considers that the value of `array` may be `None` (the first argument list, which it maps to an empty string); otherwise, `fold` takes the defined sequence (in the second argument list) then processes each member.

The `flatMap` operations convert `People` instances to the corresponding required optional values (`name` and `tall`), retrieving the defined values while filtering out those that are undefined. (`flatMap` is equivalent to a `map` followed by `flatten`.) Since the `fat` field is not optional, only a `map` is required, instead of `flatMap`.

Resulting `Boolean` values must be converted into capitalized strings through another `map` operation, in order to match your required output. (In the case of `fat`, this can be combined with the `map` call that converts `People` instances to a `Boolean` value.)

Finally, the resulting `Seq[String]`'s are joined into a single `String` using the virgule ("|") as a *separator* via the `mkString` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `mkString` is a method of `Seq[String]`

```
val names = array.map(_.flatMap(x => x.name).mkString("|")).getOrElse("")
val tall = array.map(_.flatMap(_.tall).map(_.toString.capitalize).mkString("|")).getOrElse("")
val fat = array.map(_.map(_.fat.toString.capitalize).mkString("|")).getOrElse("")
```

Comment: This doesn't work (`array` is an `Option[Seq[People]]`, some fields in `People` are themselves `Option`s, and there's no `.slot_name` member that belongs to anything).

Comment: I was assuming the field was not in the case class but it does exist and it is a Option[String] since it is explicitly asking about thst field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167219/discussion-between-mikel-and-mike-allen).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `collect` over an `array` of elements

```
val array = Seq(
    People(Some("Jack"), Some(true), true),
    People(Some("Tom"), Some(true), false),
    People(Some("Sam"), Some(true), true)
)
array: Seq[People] = List(People(Some(Jack),Some(true),true), People(Some(Tom),Some(true),false), People(Some(Sam),Some(true),true))
```

For getting name(s) of all people

```
scala> val name = array.collect{
  case p : People => p.name
}.flatten.mkString("|")
    res3: name: String = Jack|Tom|Sam
```

For getting all tall(s) of people

```
scala> val tall = array.collect{
  case p: People => p.tall
}.flatten.mkString("|")
 tall: String = true|true|true
```

Same way for fat(s)

```
scala> val tall = array.collect{
  case p: People => p.fat.toString.capitalize
}.mkString("|")
tall: String = True|False|True
```